# checking analytics setup for page I do not own

Tags: google-analytics, uri, analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics

I'm a consumer data analyst who is not very familiar to coding other than occasional encounters with HTML and Python, and I'm just starting with the coding part of Web Analytics. In particular, I need to learn about checking websites I don't own (therefore I don't have access to their Analytics accounts) for tracking info, but it has been phenomenally hard to find information on which tracking function each component of code stand for, or to what extent it is visible from the page source.

For a project, [here](https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/emlak-isyeri-satilik-bayrampasa-merkezde-102-m2-dukkan-krediye-uygun-443979107/detay) is a page I'm trying to check for Google Analytics/Tag Manager/alternative analytics setup, and see what is exactly being tracked on it. Other than the source code, I checked it with Ghostery, which gave me [this Tag Manager code page](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-58T6ZP). Is it possible to check tracking info from these two (events, pageviews, URI and how many custom dimensions there is, specifically), and which part of the code includes that info (particularly URI and dimension info - the first two, I have more idea about)?

[This](https://semtr.com/) is a page I'm also looking into. I can see that this one has Google Analytics/Tag manager, but again, I can't make sure of what is being tracked, and whether the Analytics/Tag Manager setup is looking -potentially- problematic in any way. [Here](https://gcache.ghostery.com/tr/gcache/?n=Google%20Tag%20Manager%20Web%20Tracking&s=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google-analytics.com%2Fgtm%2Fjs%3Fid%3DGTM-KJGH9K%26cid%3D992219469.1508613339&v=2&t=script) is the Tag Manager page for this one that I obtained through Ghostery.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are looking for is Google Tag Assistant extension for google chrome: https://get.google.com/tagassistant/

you can download it from here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en

When you install it it will appear as icon on any page you visit and it will show you all GA implementations on a page:

[image]

You can select tracking ID you are interested in and it will tell you how many Page Views/events were fired for that particular tracking ID only:

[image]

Then you can select individual tracking event/page view and see all data that are being sent with that tracking request. Just Click on URLs and click the icon to put the data in table:

[image]

Here "cd" stands for Custom Dimension, so here you can clearly see 2 custom dimensions that are being tracked:

[image]

Hope this helps, good luck!